# How do I resolve duplicate property errors in this j2ee schema?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, xsd, weblogic

I inherited a J2EE app written for deployment on Weblogic 10 and the developer primarily responsible for this application does not get this error when he opens the project in Eclipse.

I have the following very simple `weblogic.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/920/weblogic-web-app.xsd">   
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Eclipse generates a single XML validation problem for this file, which actually consists of a number of the same errors. The parent text of the XML problem is this:

> The errors below were detected when validating the file "j2ee_1_4.xsd"
> via the file "weblogic.xml".  In most cases these errors can be
> detected by validating "j2ee_1_4.xsd" directly.  However it is
> possible that errors will only occur when j2ee_1_4.xsd is validated in
> the context of weblogic.xml.

And an example of the child errors. They all read this way:

> sch-props.correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee,descriptionGroup'.

This is followed by a line number. There are about 50 of these errors, and only the quoted name at the end of the error changes.

I found the following bug in Sun's bug tracker which seemed to indicate a possible cause, but I'm not sure how I'd apply it to my project, if it's even relevant.

[Impossible to create javax.xml.validation.Schema instance from "web-app_2_4.xsd"](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6402288)

I can't help but think that this is related to my Eclipse configuration, but at this point I'm at a loss.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I found an article online about needing to update to the latest schema so I looked through Oracle for latest schemas versions here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/index.html

I modified my weblogic.xml file with the following:

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

...
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Regards,
Jose

Answer (score 0):

You say this is written for WL 10.

My `weblogic.xml` begins as

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
```

`http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd"`

```
xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
```

while I can see yours points to the Weblogic 9 namespace

```
xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
```

Does changing this make a difference?